# Confusing Classical Mechanics Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I don't want this to be a "do my home work question" so please tell me how I can make this question helpful for other people.

In my physics assignment I found the question below. I'd think that both FBD's and $F_{net}$s are the same for each scenario; since the track is friction-less the rider doesn't need to input anything to maintain a constant velocity.

If it helps, the answers for 'c' were found to be: $ac = g\tan(\theta)$, $a = g\sin(\theta)$ for each respective scenario.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Problem text]

Comment: How are the FBDs and Fnets the same if the accelerations are different? In one, there is centripetal acceleration while in the other there is linear.

Comment: That Might be it, maybe I'm interpreting it wrong I thought "rolling down" meant like rolling along the track. I still don't understand how ac = g*tan(ɵ) comes along tho...

Comment: Well, as ja72 pointed out, both are limits of a more general solution of a track that is inclines in two directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an object following a track with speed $v$, you can decompose the velocity vector and acceleration vector as follows:

$$ \vec{v} = v \hat{e} \\
\vec{a} = \dot{v} \hat{e} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \hat{n} $$

where $\hat{e}$ is the tangent vector, and $\vec{n}$ the normal vector, but you already know that (I hope).

In 2nd case $\rho=\infty$ and in the first case the path curvature $\rho$ is finite. To tie all this with the FBD you need to decompose the applied forces along $\hat{e}$ and $\hat{n}$ to see what contributes to speed change $\dot{v}$ and what to reaction force.

Comment: I think this one is beyond the scope of my class, but I think I understand it. Very cool solution.